# Password Policies to be set for User credentials in hac and BackOffice in Hybris 6.7

Tags: passwords, sap-commerce-cloud, backoffice

We have a requirement where in we need to set the Password Policies like
-1 Digit to be mandatory.
-1 Special character to be mandatory
-length to be minimum 8-25 characters.

Additionally we need to implement password history upto to last 3 password set, only for hac and Backoffice users i.e for Employee group.

Is there any OOTB features available to achieve this.Pointers for this requirements will be very helpful.
We are using hybris 6.7.0.0 version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hybris offers OOTB(Out Of The Box) the possibility to set password policies for employees.
This can be achieved by

- setting multiple regex in **local.properties** which will be used for validating the new password. Ex:

  **password.policy.regex.required.mustcontainuppercaseletter=.*[A-Z]+.***
- specifying the user group for which these policies will apply

  **password.policy.regex.groups.included=CustomUserGroupOnWhichPoliciesWillApply**
- configuring some internationalized messages to be displayed when a certain policy is not met

  **password.policy.*violation*.regex.required.mustcontainuppercaseletter=Password must contain at least 1 upper case letter.**

More information about setting the password policies can be seen here: https://help.sap.com/viewer/d0224eca81e249cb821f2cdf45a82ace/1905/en-US/dfeec89a46c64774892b46936d65d530.html

Comment: dj_frunza: I tried it for employee group.It is still not working. Do we need to do any customisation for it to work?

Comment: Have you performed a build(i.e "ant clean all") or restarted the server so that the new properties are taken into consideration ?

Comment: dj_frunza :Yes build was done..any further pointers will be of great help...

Comment: I did this exactly on hybris 6.7.0.0 Version. From what I just checked there were no additional configurations required. Please check once more the link I provided in the answer, maybe you can find something there

Comment: dj_frunza -Thanks...It worked..Just restarted the server again...